# How save date fields in django model?

Tags: python, django

I  can't save an object through form from model because i get an error that says "sportsession.date may not be NULL"

models.py

```
class SportSession(models.Model):
session_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
sport_type = models.ForeignKey(SportType)
date = models.DateField()
usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)

def __unicode__(self):  # python 2
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class SportSessionForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = SportSession
    exclude = ("usuario", "date", "session_id")
```

views.py

```
def sport(request):
  form = SportSessionForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    form_data = form.cleaned_data  # obtenemos la info del formulario
    obj = SportSession.objects.create()
    obj.name = form_data.get("name")
    obj.sport_type = form_data.get("sport_type")
    obj.date = date.today()
    obj.save()
  context = {
    "sport_session_form": form,
  }
  return render(request, "sport.html", context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `create` method if you want to add object data later, just create an instance of it:

```
obj = SportSession()
obj.name = form_data.get("name")
obj.sport_type = form_data.get("sport_type")
obj.date = date.today()
obj.usuario = request.user  # You need to set this as well to appropriate user instance
obj.save()
```

The error you get was because `date` field in your model can't be null but you were trying to create an object using `SportSession.objects.create()` without passing in the required data.

Note: You have `usuario` field which can't be null as well (see my note in code).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)` in models.py to automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.(see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield)